# using java for Arabic NLP

Tags: java, nlp, arabic

I'm working on Arabic natural language processing such as word stemming, tokenization etc.
In order to deal with words/chars, I need to write arabic letters in java. So, my question is that is it a good practice to write arabic letters in java directly without encoding?
example:
which one is better:

```
if(word.startsWith("ت"){...}
```

or

```
if(word.startsWith("\u1578"){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write Arabic letters for the sake of readability. As for the machine, there is no big difference. Also set your character coding to UTF-8 as Arabic characters have issues with ASCII coding set.
If you are familiar with Python, then NLTK module will be of great help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the real characters in your master copy, ensuring your compiler is configured for the correct encoding. You can always run it through `native2ascii` if you need the escaped version for any reason. Once you get going you may well find you don't actually have that many hard-coded strings in the source code, as things like gazetteer lists of potential named entities etc. are better represented as external text files.

[GATE](http://gate.ac.uk) has a basic named entity annotation plugin for Arabic which may be a good starting point for your work (full disclosure: I'm one if the GATE core development team).